# Does this metric make sense?

Tags: matrices

I have two matrices ${\bf H_1}$ and ${\bf H_2}$, Id like to create a metric that describes how close there singular values are assume  ${\bf H_1}$ has eigen values $\lambda_{11}$ and $\lambda_{12}$  in decreasing order and ${\bf H_2}$ has eigen values $\lambda_{21}$ and $\lambda_{22}$ in decreasing order,, can i say a good metric is

$$\frac{|\lambda_{11}- \lambda_{12}| + |\lambda_{21}- \lambda_{22}| }{\lambda_{11}+\lambda_{12}}$$

And if it makes sense does it mean the closer this metric is to zero the more the  matrices' eigenvalues match? Also is this metric between 0 and 1?

THANKS

Comment: What if $\lambda_{11} = - \lambda_{12}$?

Comment: Oops I didnt think of that ;(

Comment: Can you please help me create a reasonable metric

Comment: I don't know much about functional analysis, and I don't know what is motivating your question, but if by metric you refer to the metric spaces' concept of distance, you will need an operation that verifies $d(A,B) = 0$ if and only if $A = B$. Two matrices can have the same eigenvalues, and still be very different.

Comment: Thanks. I knw that the matrices can be very different and have same eigen values..but actually my application cares about the eigen values only.. I'm working on wireless communication problem and eigen values represent kind of power of channel

Comment: I see. Again, I'm far from knowledgeable in the subject, but maybe you are interested on a pseudodistance, that is, a distance with the exception that $d(A,B) = 0$ may not imply $A = B$ (the converse does however hold).